# Combination of continuous and discontinuous functions

Tags: functions, continuity

I know that combining two continuous functions gives a continuous function, i.e., if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, then $f(x)\pm g(x)$, $f(x)\times g(x)$ and $f(x)\div g(x)$ are continuous provided $g(x)\neq 0$. But what if $f(x)$ is continuous and $g(x)$ are discontinuous and we want to determine what type of function $f(x)\times g(x)$ is.
I have tried something out to prove that it will be discontinuous.

> Let $h(x)=f(x)\times g(x)$.
>    Thus,  $g(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}$, where $f(x)\neq 0$
>
> If $h(x)$ is continuous, then $g(x)$ is also continuous. But this is contrary to our assumption.
>
> So, $h(x)$ must be discontinuous.
>   So, $f(x)\times g(x)$ must be discontinuous.

This is alright but when I asked my teacher he said that the multiplication can yield both sort of functions, continuous and discontinuous. So, what have I missed in my derivation?
Should I have considered something else as well or was my conclusion wrong?

Comment: Careful. Let f=1 and g=x. Is f/g everywhere continuous? oops i see you ruled out g = 0...nevermind. How did you derive g(x)?

Comment: f(x) = 0 will yield a continuous function after multiplication.

Comment: @drawnonward as you can see, I did not derive $g(x)$. All I did was to try to represent it in terms of two functions whom I can say are continuous. My doubt in the proof is that, what are the exceptions and how can they be accounted for in this proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have proven that if $f(x)\neq 0$ and $g$ is not continuous, then $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is not continuous. Your proof is correct.

However, if $f(x)$ can be allowed to have zero values, all bets are off. For example, if $f(x)=0$ for all values of $x$, then $f\cdot g$ will be continuous *no matter what* the function $g$ is.

Comment: Does that mean that the multiplication operation may yield a continuous as well as a discontinuous function depending on the situation ?

Comment: Exactly. It yields a discontinuous function if $f\neq 0$, and a continuous if $f\equiv 0$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You remark in your proof that $f(x)\neq 0$, but it's perfectly reasonable that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I did that because it was coming as a denominator.

Comment: Yes, you did it because you'd be wrong if you didn't--- because as you said, you put it in a denominator. But the fact remains that it's entirely possible that $f(x)=0$, because $f(x)$ didn't *start out* in a denominator. My answer is the same as 5xnum's so if you understand eir's better then you're not missing out. (Except, he said and I should have: your proof is totally valid, it just doesn't prove what you wanted it to prove.)

Comment: Oh okay! I think I understand now. So if I do not assume anything out of the blue, then the the type of function depends on the situation.

Comment: @Ris97: Exactly :) And the proof you did produce gives you a bonus fact: the only way that a discontinuous point $x$ of $g$ can become a continuous point of $h$ is if $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well! Its not necessary that one of the functions must be zero.
For ex- take |x| as f(x) and sgn(x) as g(x). Now their product is |x|sgn(x) which is continuous. U can check its continuity on 0 as its the only suspicious point. And their left hand side limit and right hand side limit will come same.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please avoid using abbreviations like  "U" for "you" :)

Comment: Ohh..OK. thanks.

Comment: But here the function $f(x)=|x|$ is $0$ at $x=0$, which is the point that we are interested in. So indeed $f$ need not be equal to $0$ everywhere, but at those "suspicious points".